# Displaying direct children of other pages on homepage

Tags: pages, children

I am trying to display the DIRECT children of another page on the homepage but I can't seem to get it working it just shows all of the page titles on the site..

It needs to be within a wp_query as I require to use advanced custom fields on the pages

My code:

```
<?php

            $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'parent' => 42, 'child_of' => 0,) );

                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                    echo '<h3>'; the_title(); echo '</h3>';

                    echo '<p>' ; the_field('enter_stuff_here'); echo '</p>';

                endwhile;

                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

My understanding was if I used the ID of the parent that this would show all of the DIRECT children of this page (please note I don't want t o show grandchildren but ONLY DIRECT child pages)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I just realised it had to be 'post_parent' => 42 - i'm an idiot!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'parent' => 42, 'child_of' => 0,) );
```

You should edit this line like following:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => 42) );
```